# Testing User Login in Django using Selenium

Tags: python, django, selenium

In Django / Selenium, do you need to always input the **username** and **password** as strings since when you call the password from the user it outputs a hashed password, and then if Selenium inputs that into the window it won't let you login using the hashed password?

This code of mine works:

```
def test_admin_login(self):
    # users types in username and passwords and presses enter
    self.browser.get(self.live_server_url + '/admin/')
    username_field = self.browser.find_element_by_name('username')
    username_field.send_keys('admin')
    password_field = self.browser.find_element_by_name('password')
    password_field.send_keys('1234')
    password_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)


    # login credentials are correct, and the user is redirected to the main admin page
    body = self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
    self.assertIn('Site administration', body.text)
```

However,
If I switch out "admin" for lets say

```
admin = User.objects.get(username="admin")
```

and call the admin password like so:

```
password_field.send_keys(admin.password)
```

It inputs the hashed password into the browser and won't let me login.

Any other way to do this then using the string of the password?

Thanks,
Aaron

Comment: why do you want to do what you describe in your question?

Comment: You'd better enter log-in information each time and not interfere overall functionality of the system by using hashed passwords or anything else. I should also mention that selenium does not log-in you automatically unless you load it with a specific profile. You can fix such settings in a profile and load selenium with that.

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasi, I did run into the Login issue that you're talking about where it wouldn't log me in or allow for any testing with Logged in Users.  Do you know what setting I would want to change to do this?  Or just login via a command, and have Selenium open up and take it from there?  Thnx

Comment: I don't think there would be any problem if you use selenium to log  into your web-site. Can you just explain me a little more about how you do log-in action and provide me some code please?

Answer (score 2):

If you work with test database, create set password for need user.

```
def login_as(self, browser, user):
    # change password
    password = 'q'
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()

    browser.get(self.live_server_url + '/admin/')
    username_field = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('form input[name="username"]')
    password_field = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('form input[name="password"]')
    username_field.send_keys(user.username)
    password_field.send_keys(password)

    submit = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('form input[type="submit"]')
    submit.click()
```

Comment: how and where can it be specified to use Test Database or Project database.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the answer to your questions is most likely No. The reason being that you never want to store a password in plain text without hashing it (and ideally also salting it). It IS POSSIBLE nevertheless to configure Django to not hash your password before storing it in your database. If you don't hash it then you can do what you want:

```
admin = User.objects.get(username="admin")
password_field.send_keys(admin.password)
```

I would NOT recommend this. Also, it's not possible to use the hashed version of the password in your login page to login either as the Django authentication backend will hash the already hashed input and it will NOT match.

Does this make sense?